# Fetch 401 Authorization issue

Tags: reactjs, woocommerce, fetch-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I've started to build a project using WooComeerce and React.js, but I have one question.
When I try to get the data, for example: "products", received an issue 401 unauthorized..
I've tested my request into Postman/Insomnia and everything is working as expected. I think the problem is coming from the headers part, but for now I can't handle the issue..

Also my response headers are **empty**!

Here is my code:

```
const getProducts = async () => {
const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}products?consumer_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_CONSUMER_KEY}&${process.env.REACT_APP_CONSUMER_SECRED_KEY}`,
  {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Basic ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_CONSUMER_KEY}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);

return response;
};
```

How can i fix that issue?

**Note**: I'm not using WooCommerce REST API package.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the basic auth string is base64-encoded string `username:password`. However i see the consumer key being used in the req and the header. Can you please double check your authorization header?